# How can I load a trained autoencoder (Keras), take the encoder part, and freeze it?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

I trained an autoencoder, and would now like to use the encoder part (including weights) for another purpose. Can I load the full model, get the encoder part, and then set the 'trainable' parameter in these layers? Or do I need to recompile the adapted encoder architecture (i.e. all layers set to untrainable), and only then load the weights?

Comment: Oh, it's that simpel huh. Cool, I read something about needing to compile after setting the flags, so I figure that wouldn't work. Model summary tells me it does. Thanks!

Comment: Do you require the code ( as an answer )?

Comment: Basically just did this: `encoder.get_layer(index=1).trainable = False` throughout the relevant layers. Seems to work, the summary says there are no more trainable parameters (haven't tried training though).

Comment: That seems to be correct. Go ahead and train the model.

Comment: Just to come back to the issue, everything seems to have worked. Thanks! Can't accept the answer, because it's a comment, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the model list of layers ( `model.layers` ) and modify the layers of encoder so that `trainable` flag is `False`.

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```